Next.js Configuration Issue: publicRuntimeConfig.root Undefined and Fetching undefined URL
I'm working on a Next.js project where I need to serve a VRM file located in the public directory. I already setted up my configuration, but the fetched publicRuntimeConfig.root remains 'undefined', while I had intended it to be "" such that it can be accessed under the public directory.
My next.config.cjs is as follows:
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['rc-util', 'antd']);

console.log("Environment variables:", process.env);
throw new Error("Testing if config is executed");

const basePath = process.env.BASE_PATH || "";

console.log("BASE_PATH:", basePath);

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  assetPrefix: process.env.BASE_PATH || "",
  basePath: process.env.BASE_PATH || "",
  trailingSlash: true,
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    root: process.env.BASE_PATH || "",
  },
  optimizeFonts: false,
  transpilePackages: [...],
  env: {
    BASE_PATH: process.env.BASE_PATH,
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

and buildUrl.ts is as follows:
import getConfig from "next/config";

export function buildUrl(path: string): string {
  const {
    publicRuntimeConfig,
  }: {
    publicRuntimeConfig: { root: string };
  } = getConfig();

  const fullUrl = publicRuntimeConfig.root + path;
  console.log(`Built URL: ${fullUrl}`);
  console.log(`publicRuntimeConfig.root: ${publicRuntimeConfig.root}`);
  return fullUrl;
  //return publicRuntimeConfig.root + path;
}

which is used here in vrmViewer.tsx ...viewer.loadVrm(buildUrl("/mind.vrm"));
my .env is simply BASE_PATH="", I left it blank because originally I didn't have any .env files. I added later on noticing that process.env uses my local env paths.
I suspected that next.config.cjs wasn't accessed at all because console.log("Environment variables:", process.env); console.log("BASE_PATH:", basePath); did not process, while in buildUrl.ts both console logs are processed.
Can anyone help me to see why I keep getting "/undefined/mind.vrm " instead of "/mind.vrm"?
